# Code won't run due to string length issue

Tags: javascript

Got a simple Javascript program here to accept and check a password. It should:

1. Ask you to enter a new password
2. Check the strength of the password which outputs a message of either weak or strong based on a length of <6 or >6.
3. Get you to re enter this password to enter the 'system'
4. Give you simple prompts or 2 random letters if the password is not correct.

Everything works except the strong/weak checker. It has a problem getting the length of passwordEntry since it apparently doesn't exist as an entity.

Any ideas would be much appreciated

```
var pass;
var main = function(){
strengthCheck((prompt("Please Choose a New Password to Begin"));
}

var strengthCheck = new function(passwordEntry){
score = 0;
// adds to the score variable depending on the length of the password
if(passwordEntry.length > 6{
score=(score+1);
}
//reads messages back stating how strong password is based on length
if(score=0){
console.log("Your Password is Weak");
}
else if(score=1){
console.log("Your Password is Strong");
}
var passContinue = prompt("Do you want to continue with this password? Yes or no?")
if(passContinue === "no" ||  passContinue === "No"{
main();
}
else{
pass = passwordEntry;
console.log("Your new password has been changed to " + pass);
passwordChecker(prompt("Thank You. Please Enter Your Password Below"));
}
}

var passwordChecker = function (attempt){
if(attempt == pass){
    console.log("Correct password. The system has logged you on");
}
    else{
    //if the password is wrong, runs the incorrectpassword() function
        console.log("Incorrect Password");
        IncorrectPass();
        }
    }
}

var IncorrectPass = function (){
var clueanswer = prompt("Do You Want A Clue");
if(clueanswer === "Yes" ||clueanswer === "yes"){    
console.log("I will give you two random letters");
// takes two random locations from the string array and reads them back
var randarray1 = Math.floor((Math.random()*7)+1);
var randarray2 = Math.floor((Math.random()*7)+1);
var randletter1 = pass[randarray1];
var randletter2 = pass[randarray2];
console.log(randletter1+" "+randletter2);
passwordChecker("Please try entering your password again");  
}
    else{
        console.log("GoodBye");
    }
}

main()
```

Comment: Missing ) on if(passwordEntry.length > 6{ ?

Comment: Are you sure this is the actual code you use? There's also an extra `(` on line 3.

Comment: Upvote ALL the answers and comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this...

```
var strengthCheck = new function(passwordEntry){
```

to this...

```
var strengthCheck = function(passwordEntry){
```

When you use `new`, you're not using it to create a new function. You're using it to call the function as a constructor, which will return an object. *(An empty object in your case.)*

Also, you have many syntax errors in your code. Use a code validator like http://jshint.com as well as a beautifier like http://jsbeautifier.org to clean up your code.

Comment: Thanks, fixed. There were a few other errors with the extra brackets and such which are all now fixed.

Answer (score 3):

This part looks very wrong:

```
if(score=0){
  console.log("Your Password is Weak");
}
else if(score=1){
  console.log("Your Password is Strong");
}
```

You should use `==` or `===` instead of `=` which is used for assignment rather than comparison.

This doesn't make sense either:

```
var main = function(){
  strengthCheck((prompt("Please Choose a New Password to Begin"));
}
```

There are three opening parentheses and only two closing ones. Smells like parser error.